# Disable faulty Caps Lock key permanently

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I've an old laptop with a faulty <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key that switches on and off continuously.

I found these commands to disable the key:

```
xmodmap -e "remove lock = Caps_Lock"
```

and

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

Both commands seems to work properly, but the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> seems to change state without intervention intermittently. Furthermore, this doesn't seem to have effect on the display manager login screen and after waking the laptop from sleep the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is enabled again automatically.

I could run `xdotool key Caps_Lock` to toggle the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> but this would only be necessary when the Caps Lock gets stuck in the On state.

To check the state of the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> I could use `xset -q | grep Caps` but I can't find of a way to  disabling the key permanently.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 =' `

Comment: Don't know, but here are places to look: If you permanently remove it from your layout, it should be gone. https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/769644-hacking-your-linux-keyboard-with-xkb
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Configuration